# No module name pwd

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

**I am trying to connect Mysql to Django
**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djsql',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'root',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',

    }}
```

tried running :
`pip install mysqlclient`

and
`python manage.py migrate`

Getting Error:

```
 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u0zn06ml\migrate_37874a5e96fe48ffb9d7bebe813702bc\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
          import migrate
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u0zn06ml\migrate_37874a5e96fe48ffb9d7bebe813702bc\migrate.py", line 18, in <module>
          import pwd
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

not able to find the error pwd!!

Comment: What command are you actually running when you get this error?

Comment: _tried running : `pip install msqlclient`_ Is that a typo?  Did you actually mean `mysqlclient`?  The `y` is missing.

Comment: Good call @JohnGordon. However, there's no such module on Pypi

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry it was a typo mistake I have tried the same command to run the programme.

Comment: `pwd` isn't available on Windows.

Comment: @gre_gor ,why I am getting this error, do you have any solution or any alternate way to solve the error?

Comment: @SujataR  you've been already asked what command you're running when you get this error.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack i have already mentioned the commands i.e  tried running : pip install mysqlclient

and python manage.py migrate

Comment: @SujataR which one gives the error message? `pip install` **or** `python manage`? It can be only one.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack pip install for installing mysqlclient and for connecting need to migrate the data to database so " python manage.py migrate" is use after this I am getting error

Comment: @SujataR once you've run `pip install mysqlclient`, you do not need to run it again. Please update your question to show the command you're typing into the shell and all of the output including the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are encountering seems to be a Windows-specific issue as `pwd` module is typically used in Unix-like systems. The `mysqlclient` library uses `C` bindings. It is possible that some of the dependencies of the library are not supported on Windows. Many modules are not supported on Windows (like [`buildozer`](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you have ever used a module to make IOS or Android applications {not related to `mysqlclient` by the way} {`pwd` in the case of `mysqlclient`}). You may consider using other modules like [`mysql-connector-python`](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) or [`pymysql`](https://pypi.org/project/pymysql/).

Here is an example using `pymysql`:

- First, install the `pymysql` library:
  `pip install pymysql`
- Then, in your `Django` `settings.py`, modify the `DATABASES` configuration to use `pymysql`:

  ```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'djsql',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
                'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            },
            'CONN_MAX_AGE': 300,
        }
    }
  ```

Make sure to replace the database settings according to your MySQL setup.

- After making these changes, try running the migrations again:
  `python manage.py migrate`

This should work on Windows without encountering the `pwd` module issue. If you still encounter problems, check the documentation of the chosen library (`pymysql` in this case) for any additional configuration needed on Windows. Hope this helps (: